# Software for diagramming food webs?

Tags: xenobiology, software-recommendations

My friends and I have a huge hyperrealistic worldbuilding project (yes, I do suffer from Worldbuilder's Disease) that involves speculative biology. I am currently using [diagrams.net](https://diagrams.net) to make the cladograms, but food webs are a bigger challenge. Do any of you know software that could be used to make a food web? It would have to work on Chrome OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After quickly asking Mr Google “food web maker software”, here’s what I’ve got:

- [Creately](https://creately.com/lp/food-web-maker/)
- [Insight](https://insightmaker.com/tag/food-web)
- [Visual Paradigm](https://online.visual-paradigm.com/diagrams/templates/interrelationship-diagram/food-chain-interrelationship-diagram/)

This is by no means a comprehensive list, but hopefully this helps :)